# How do get a Conditional Format to work for cell A that exceeds the value in D?

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I'm working in Excel everything is good in my values and math in cells A and B and C and using these values it figures a percentage in cell D, which creates an estimate of what the figure of cell C should be in cell E. What I need to do is highlight cell E if the value in cell C has exceeded the value in E?.

```
      A      |     B     |    C    |    D    |    E
1  265910    |   107045  |  54876  |   34%   |  58076
2  1069862   |   153947  |  63006  |   29%   |  61824
```

How do I do this with Conditional Formatting or in VBA to highlight each row independently from the next row without going cell to cell through over a hundred rows and doing a conditional format?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting can do this for you in short order:

1. First, select the first cell under C
2. click "New Rule" under "Conditional Formatting
3. click "Format only cells that contain"
4. Format only cells with: "Cell Value" in the first drop-down
5. "greater than" in the second drop down
6. Type "=E#" into the formula, but replace "#" with the row the corresponding E value is in
7. use "Format" to decide what the rule will do
8. Click "OK"
9. Re-open conditional formatting, but click "Manage rules" instead of "new rule"
10. Under "Applies to", highlight the entire column C, or highlight only cells that contain data under C by clicking the first one, then cntrl+shift+downarrow

This makes every cell do its own calculation because when you created the rule, it only applied to one cell. Then the formula doesn't contain $, which means that the formula is relative to the cell the rule applies to.

Following those steps by expanding the "Applies to" to a long series of cells causes the rule to be relative to each cell, instead of being absolute to the first cell.

Below is a picture to clarify and visualize the relative reference for you you can see that I have cell C2 selected while creating the rule, then the formula refers to E2 without Dollar Signs.

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you very much!